# Is there a difference between the new and *alloc functions when using them in an allocator?

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management, new-operator, allocator

Assuming that my purpose is to write an allocator, this allocator will serve me as an exercise; I noticed that `libstdc++` uses `new` under the hood, inside `std::allocator` ( or equivalent classes inside libstdc++, to allocate the actual memory, to be honest I was expecting a function from the `alloc` family.

Both `new` and the `*alloc` family of functions return a `void *`, and they also allocate memory, but from a design point of view there is one that shines over the other? Could you provide an example of a well written `new`, or good guidelines for `new`, in the case this operator wins over `alloc`?

My new codebase is targeted to anything that is no older than C++11, in case you need a frame of reference about language specs.

PS

with `new` I'm referring to the `new` in the global namespace obviously .

Comment: `alloc` does not throw.

Comment: There is a `nothrow` version of `new` available.

Comment: @AlexD `new` can't be `noexcept` in C++11 and newer ?

Comment: @user2485710 `new` can be `nothrow`, as RemyLebeau said.

Comment: You have not mentioned what you want your allocator to do different than a default one?

Comment: @AlexD that's what I was trying to determine from the top of my head, I was remembering a `noexcept` used in that context, so back to my question: what you all can say about that ?

Comment: @Yakk what do you mean with that ? you want to know the semantics ( about what ? ) , you need to know about usability ? I would basically like to plug in and take advantage of many optimized `alloc` functions that are platform/OS specific and different patterns like a pool allocator . It's basically experimentation over platform specific stuff with the liberty of a piece of software written by myself, the real problem is getting the design right and the difference between `new` and `*alloc` functions .

Comment: If you want to be able to change the allocator, go with the standard-libraries idea of them. Be aware that `::operator new(...)` expects a number of bytes, while `allocator::allocate(...)` expects a number of objects.

Comment: @Deduplicator I'm mumbling about how to properly write a **global** `new` operator, I mean where I'm even supposed to put it if I want all the other bits of my C++ application to auto-magically use it ?

Comment: Well, the global new is overridable (at least `operator new(size_t)` and `operator new [](size_t)` are), and the default one normally just delegates to `malloc`. It does not matter in which translation-unit you override them, but don't forget to also override the *four* global delete-operators. Choosing a better general-purpose allocator than the implementation-default one though, that might be difficult.

Comment: @Deduplicator you make it sound really good and simple, and I was thinking about this before, this also means that if I override global new before calling a standard allocator - at least as it is written in libstdc++ - I get that given *alloc with that given function with basically no effort . It looks too simple to be C++, I'll basically need to define a new allocator only for a pool allocator or other "special" cases .

Comment: If you're writing a replacement for the global `operator new` function, then you have to use `malloc`, or something similar.  Trying to use `new` will result in endless recursion.

Comment: As for using a tuned version of `malloc`: although not guaranteed by the standard, you can pretty much assume that the standard `operator new` function uses `malloc` under the hood.

Answer (score 4):

There are two major differences.  The first is that the `malloc` and company
return a null pointer if there is no more memory, so you'd have to check that,
and throw `std::bad_alloc` if you get a null pointer back; the `operator new`
function frees you of this, since it will throw `std::bad_alloc` if it cannot
allocate the memory.  The second is that the user can replace the `operator
new`/`operator delete` functions; this is commonly done in debug builds to
track memory leaks and dangling pointers.  (In practice, you can probably do
this with `malloc` as well, but formally, doing so is undefined behavior.)